# How to disable the content when button was clicked

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I need to disable the content or put an overlay in my project. I have a floating button when this floating button clicked I need to expand some images in the right corner(I did this part). Also, I need when the button clicked it needs to overlay the current content. the problem is I need custom code for that when button clicked it should overlay.

**My content view:**

```
<StackLayout   BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=navi}"  >
<StackLayout >
<customRenderes:NavigationImageButton Source="MenuSettings"                                               x:Name="Button1"                                                       Margin="0" IsVisible="{Binding Visibility1}" />                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
</stacklayout>
<content View>
```

This is how I called this whenever I need that floating button

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
<views:Page1 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,-1,-1" ></views:Page1>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

I need to add an overlay also I cannot mess with all my pages so it should include in the  ContentView page. How to do it, How to add a popup overlay in contentview.

Comment: https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Comment: yes but did not want to use any nuget.

Comment: @G.hakim  also I need to disable or cloak other areas when my float action button clicked and its activities need to happen when I touch again the other area float button should collapse

Comment: I didn't understand a thing you said you confused me even further

Comment: @G.hakim  I have a float action button when I clicked that button it expand a some buttons. when it happen my other content is touchable  I want to give focus to my expanded button and blur the other content. Do you get it now

Comment: You can add the popView on contentView in advance and set the isVisible as false.Then set it as true as you need,

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT can you desicribe it in as a answer

Comment: yes it works  you can provide an answer then I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

You can add the view in stacklayout in advance.And set the property **IsVisible** as false.

```
<StackLayout >

    <!-->... <-->
    <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="myView" IsVisible="False">
        <ContentView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,-1,-1" ></ContentView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
    <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked"  Text="showMyView" />

</StackLayout>
```

When you want to show it ,set it as true.For example when you click a button.

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  myView.IsVisible = true;
}
```